# Populating a google pie chart in Angular from a Json comming from back-end

Tags: angular, spring-boot, google-visualization

I am getting a problem to correcly populate a google pie chart.

[I am building a view. **Do not consider the table**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnWYr.png) 
and I am doing progress.

But, My onInit method get a json from spring boot and tries to set on a property defined as **employees**. Check it out on the end of the method:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup , Validators} from '@angular/forms'; 

import { Employee } from "src/app/ab-front/employee.interface";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { EmployeesService } from "src/app/ab-front/employees/employees.service";
import { OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'ab-employee',
    templateUrl: 'employee.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['employee.component.css']

})

export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit { 


    form : FormGroup;

    employees: Employee [] = [];

    @Input()
    pieChartData =  {
        chartType: 'PieChart',
        options: {'title': 'Dados do Pessoal',
                pieHole:0.4,
                chartArea: {
                    left:100,
                    top:50,
                    width: 400,
                    height: 300}

        },
        dataTable: this.populaChart()
    };

    populaChart(){
        let titulo : string [] = ['Nome','Participacao'];
        let linha = [];
        for(let i = 0 ; i < this.employees.length ; i++){
            linha [i] = [this.employees[i].nome + ' ' + this.employees[i].sobrenome , 
            this.employees[i].participacao];
            if(i < this.employees.length){
                linha [i] = linha [i] + ',';
            }
        }
        console.log(this.employees);
        return [
            titulo,
            ['Hugo Silva',  20],
            ['Eliza Souza', 20],
            ['Anderson Santos', 40]
        ];
    }

    constructor(private employeeService: EmployeesService,
        private formBuilder : FormBuilder){ }

        ngOnInit(){
            this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
                nome: ['', 
                    [
                        Validators.required,
                        Validators.pattern('([A-Z])([a-z])+'),
                        Validators.minLength(2)
                    ],
                ],
                sobrenome: ['', 
                    [
                        Validators.required,
                        Validators.pattern('([A-Z])([a-z])+'),
                        Validators.minLength(2)
                    ]
                ],
                participacao: ['', 
                    [
                        Validators.required,
                        Validators.pattern('[0-9]+'),
                        Validators.minLength(1)
                    ]
                ]
            });
                this.employeeService
                .listEmployees()
                .subscribe(employees => {
                    this.employees = employees;                    
                    console.log(this.employees);
                });    
        }
}
```

above, that console.log prints a json with 2 elements.
Yet, I try to do the same on populaChart method and there, 
[I got an empty variable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUe4Y.png)

Do someone know what happen? And also, how can I set data to my pie chart from a json comming from back end and from my form ?

Answer (score 1):

When the following code is compiled to JavaScript, `pieChartData = ...` is placed in the constructor, which runs before `ngOnInit`:

```
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
    // Runs in the constructor 
    pieChartData =  {
        chartType: 'PieChart',
        options: {'title': 'Dados do Pessoal',
                pieHole:0.4,
                chartArea: {
                    left:100,
                    top:50,
                    width: 400,
                    height: 300}

        },
        dataTable: this.populaChart()
    };

    ngOnInit() {
        // Runs after the constructor
        // Get employees
    }
}
```

So when it runs, you don't have any employees yet. You should create `pieChartData` inside `ngOnInit`, after you have received `employees` from the API. Or at least initialize `dataTable` to an empty array, and update it later when you have employees.